# Command queueing per tick or per body part

Tags: javascript, screeps

The command queueing is not completely clear to me from the documentation. Are the commands like move and attack per bodypart, or is there only one action per tick and does it act on the first successful one?

Let's say I have a simple attacker creep with:

```
...
creep.moveTo( enemy );
creep.attack( enemy );
...
```

What will happen in the next tick when the creep is one step away from the enemy?

1. Will it try to move, then attack
2. Will it try to attack, fail, then try to move (first in, last out)
3. Will it only move (first in, first out, one action)

And now for example:

```
...
creep.attack( enemy );
creep.moveTo( enemy );
creep.attack( enemy );
...
```

Will it try to attack, fail, then move, then try attack again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be possible to do both ranged melee and move actions in 1 turn. but you canonly perform 1 of these actions. So you can't attack or move 2 times during a frame. As far as i can tell the last called event takes priority.

For example:
    creep.attack(target1);
    creep.attack(target2);

The creep here will attack target2 first. If target2 is undefined he will go for target1

Answer (score 3):

From what I've seen, the creep does everything it can per tick, as I've seen ranged attacks and moves happen at the same time.  I'd be willing to bet that it's a "attack phase then move phase" kind of thing, everything attacks, then everything moves.